# C#: Setting all values in an array with arbitrary dimensions

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm looking for a way to set every value in a multidimensional array to a single value.  The problem is that the number of dimensions is unknown at compile-time - it could be one-dimensional, it could be 4-dimensional.  Since `foreach` doesn't let you set values, what is one way that I could achieve this goal?  Thanks much.

Comment: Jagged arrays or multi-dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**While this problem appears simple on the surface, it's actually more complicated than it looks.** However, by recognizing that visiting every position in a multidimensional (or even jagged) array is a *Cartesian product operation* on the set of indexes of the array - we can simplify the solution ... and ultimately write a more elegant solution.

**We're going to leverage [Eric Lippert's LINQ Cartesian Product](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) implementation to do the heavy lifting.** You can read more about how that works on his blog if you like.

While this implementation is specific to visiting the cells of a multidimensional array -  it should be relatively easy to see how to extend it to visit a jagged array as well.

```
public static class EnumerableExt
{
    // Eric Lippert's Cartesian Product operator...
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
          this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = 
                   new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
        return sequences.Aggregate(
          emptyProduct,
          (accumulator, sequence) =>
            from accseq in accumulator
            from item in sequence
            select accseq.Concat(new[] { item }));
    }
}

class MDFill
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // create an arbitrary multidimensional array
        Array mdArray = new int[2,3,4,5];

        // create a sequences of sequences representing all of the possible
        // index positions of each dimension within the MD-array
        var dimensionBounds = 
            Enumerable.Range(0, mdArray.Rank)
               .Select(x => Enumerable.Range(mdArray.GetLowerBound(x),
                      mdArray.GetUpperBound(x) - mdArray.GetLowerBound(x)+1));

        // use the cartesian product to visit every permutation of indexes
        // in the MD array and set each position to a specific value...
        int someValue = 100;
        foreach( var indexSet in dimensionBounds.CartesianProduct() )
        {
            mdArray.SetValue( someValue, indexSet.ToArray() );
        }
    }
}
```

It's now trivial to factor this code out into a reusable method that can be used for either jagged or multidimensional arrays ... or any data structure that can be viewed as a rectangular array.

Comment: Wow, that was a really interesting read.  Thanks so much for the link and the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Array.Length will tell you the number of elements the array was declared to store, so an array of arrays (whether rectangular or jagged) can be traversed as follows:

```
for(var i=0; i<myMDArray.Length; i++)
   for(var j=0; j < myMDArray[i].Length; i++)
      DoSomethingTo(myMDArray[i][j]);
```

If the array is rectangular (all child arrays are the same length), you can get the Length of the first array and store in a variable; it will slightly improve performance.

When the number of dimensions is unknown, this can be made recursive:

```
public void SetValueOn(Array theArray, Object theValue)
{
   if(theArray[0] is Array) //we haven't hit bottom yet
      for(int a=0;a<theArray.Length;a++)
         SetValueOn(theArray[a], theValue);
   else if(theValue.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(theArray[0].GetType()))
      for(int i=0;i<theArray.Length;i++)
         theArray[i] = theValue;
   else throw new ArgumentException(
         "theValue is not assignable to elements of theArray");
}
```

Comment: @JustOnePixel - note this is the Jagged array `myArray[][]` solution

Comment: True; I didn't notice that it was the number of dimensions, not the length, that was unknown. I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no direct way of doing this, so you'll need to use the `Rank` property to get the number of dimensions and a `SetValue` method (that takes an array with index for every dimension as argument).

Some code snippet to get you started (for standard multi-dimensional arrays):

```
bool IncrementLastIndex(Array ar, int[] indices) {
  // Return 'false' if indices[i] == ar.GetLength(i) for all 'i'
  // otherwise, find the last index such that it can be incremented,
  // increment it and set all larger indices to 0
  for(int dim = indices.Length - 1; dim >= 0; dim--) { 
    if (indices[dim] < ar.GetLength(dim)) {
      indices[dim]++;
      for(int i = dim + 1; i < indices.Length; i++) indices[i] = 0;
      return;
    }
  }
}

void ClearArray(Array ar, object val) {
  var indices = new int[ar.Rank];
  do {
    // Set the value in the array to specified value
    ar.SetValue(val, indices);
  } while(IncrementLastIndex(ar, indices));
}
```

Comment: @JustOnePixel - note this is the MultiDimensional array `myArray[,]` solution

Answer (score 0):

The `Array.Clear` method will let you clear (set to default value) all elements in a multi-dimensional array (i.e., `int[,]`).  So if you just want to clear the array, you can write `Array.Clear(myArray, 0, myArray.Length);`

There doesn't appear to be any method that will set all of the elements of an array to an arbitrary value.

Note that if you used that for a jagged array (i.e. `int[][]`), you'd end up with an array of null references to arrays.  That is, if you wrote:

```
int[][] myArray;
// do some stuff to initialize the array
// now clear the array
Array.Clear(myArray, 0, myArray.Length);
```

Then `myArray[0]` would be `null`.

Answer (score -1):

Are you saying that you want to iterate through each element and (if available) each dimension of an array and set each value along the way?

If that's the case you'd make a recursive function that iterates the dimensions and sets values. Check the [Array.Rank](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.rank.aspx) property on MSDN and the [Array.GetUpperBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound.aspx) function on MSDN.

Lastly, I'm sure generic `List<T>` has some sort of way of doing this.

Comment: Actually, `List<T>` doesn't appear to have any such thing.  There's `List.Clear()`, which will set every item to its default value, but nothing that will set to an arbitrary value.