# How to set all elements in a 3D array to a single value?

Tags: c#, arrays

For my C# project, I'm working with a 16x16x16 3D char array(char[,,]) and need to set the values of all elements to char '0'. Preferably during definition (char[,,] my3Dbasis = ...). Of course, I could do this manually, but such would be extremely unconventional and not suitable for my needs. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign value in two dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408113/how-to-assign-value-in-two-dimensional-array) and [C#: Setting all values in an array with arbitrary dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805159/c-setting-all-values-in-an-array-with-arbitrary-dimensions)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079215/how-to-initialize-multi-dimensional-array-with-different-default-value

Answer (score 0):

You can do this something like this during initialization

```
char[,,] array3D = new char[2, 2, 3] 
{ 
  { 
    { '0', '0', '0' }, 
    { '0', '0', '0' }
  }, 
  { 
    { '0', '0', '0' }, 
    { '0', '0', '0' }
  }
};
```

Or just iterate over the array and set the value

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
{
  for ( int j = 0; j < 2; j++ )
  {
    for ( int k = 0; k < 3; k++ )
    {
      array3D[i, j, k] = '0';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Array.GetUpperBound](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound) is preferable to literals. Also [Array.GetLowerBound](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.getlowerbound) to be *very* scrupulous.

Comment: I assume you meant to use a `char` array and to assign `'0'` rather than `0` (since assigning `0` like that is pointless because the array will already be initialised to contain all `0` values).

Comment: Yes just changed to char array. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score -2):

Untested ...

```
fixed (int* pMyArray= MyArray){
  for (int i = 0; i < 16*16*16; i++)
    *pMyArray + i = VALUE;
}
```